# Warning not to make function within a loop

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, jslint, jshint

I've written a code to create modal windows for div container. Once the button is clicked, I get the button's number and display a related modal window.   Tested, works on all browsers.

```
myModalContent = new tingle.modal();
var myBtn = document.querySelectorAll("button.project__btn");
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
myBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    myModalContent.open();
    if (this.hasAttribute("data-btn")) {
        myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project" + this.getAttribute("data-btn") + "-modal").innerHTML);
    } else {
        myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project1-modal").innerHTML);
    }
});
```

}
A js validator gives one warning "Don't make functions within a loop."
Read some posts related to this topic, especially that the function must be created outside of the loop, I created a function:

```
 function handler(modalDiv, trigBtn, index){
    modalDiv.open();
    if (trigBtn[index].hasAttribute("data-btn")) {
        modalDiv.setContent(document.querySelector(".project" + trigBtn[index].getAttribute("data-btn") + "-modal").innerHTML);
    } else {
        modalDiv.setContent(document.querySelector(".project1-modal").innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Then called it from within a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
    myBtn[i].onclick = handler(myModalContent, myBtn, i);
}
```

It doesn't seem to work properly, it displays a last modal window right after the web page loads. My understanding that the function must be connected with the click event listener, ie when a button is clicked, the modal window should pop up. Now, the modal window pops up without any click event. Could you give me an idea how to properly write a function? Or if I should just simply ignore this js validation warning or not.

Comment: Why did you change the contents of your function, and why are you now trying to call it instead of just installing it as a handler like before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple! You do not have to change anything about your code but to move the function expression to a named function declaration outside of the loop body:

```
var myModalContent = new tingle.modal();
var myBtn = document.querySelectorAll("button.project__btn");
function myHandler() {
    myModalContent.open();
    if (this.hasAttribute("data-btn")) {
        myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project" + this.getAttribute("data-btn") + "-modal").innerHTML);
    } else {
        myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project1-modal").innerHTML);
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
    myBtn[i].addEventListener("click", myHandler);
}
```

Comment: I see. Actually, all answers are useful and helped to break the solution into pieces.
I see what you mean. After moving the chunk of code into the function expression, adding it to the event listener as a function reference. Alternatively, when the handler function returns itself, it is being used as a function call inside of the event listener.
Then, does it make sense to avoid polluting the global scope and put all code inside of IIFE (function () { // code })() ?

Comment: @holler I don't understand what you mean by "*the handler function returns itself*"?

Comment: @holler Yes, it makes sense to keep `myModalContent`, `myBtn`, `myHandler` and `i` in a local scope.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is trying to prevent a problem with "modified closures". If your function did anything with the variable `i`, then you'd find that the value of the variable `i` at the time when users click the button is always `myBtn.length` because that's the value it ends up with at the end of the loop.

This:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
...
```

Is treated like this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
...
```

Since you don't use `i` anywhere in your function, you're technically safe, but there's a possibility that other developers in the future could change the code and end up running into this problem.

In order to fix this code in the way it looks like you're trying to fix it, you'd need to have the `handler` function *return a function* itself.

```
myBtn[i].addEventListener("click", createHandler());

function createHandler() {
    return function() {
        myModalContent.open();
        if (this.hasAttribute("data-btn")) {
            myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project" + this.getAttribute("data-btn") + "-modal").innerHTML);
        } else {
            myModalContent.setContent(document.querySelector(".project1-modal").innerHTML);
        }
    };
}
```

This has the same effect as your working code, but prevents someone from trying to use `i` inside of the closure. If someone needs `i` there, they can add it to the `createHandler`'s argument list, where it's not reusing the same variable for each pass through the loop.

Alternatively, if you can use modern versions of javascript, you can use the `let` keyword instead of `var`.

This:

```
for (let i = 0; i < myBtn.length; i++) {
...
```

Is treated more like how this code would work in a language like C#:

```
for (var _ = 0; _ < myBtn.length; _++) {
    var i = _;
...
```

In other words, the scope of the `i` variable is internal to the `for` loop, rather than global to the function you're in.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you *have to return a function* in the createHandler() function. In the past, I've just written the function, `function openModal() { myModalContent.open().../* rest of code here */.. }` and then when adding the function to the event, just `myBtn[i].addEventListener('click', openModal)`. Notice in the addEventListener it isn't using parenthesis, as that will call it, in which case you would need to return a function. Since we aren't calling it, is just saying to use that function in the click event

Comment: If `createHandler` does not take any parameters, you don't need the function at all.

Comment: The warning is not because there could be an issue with closures, the warning is because there are multiple functions created where a single object would suffice. It's a performance optimisation, nothing else. (If there was a closure, multiple functions would be warranted, and the warning wouldn't occur).

Comment: @Tyler and @Bergi, you're both right that if there's no need for parameters to be passed based on the position in the `for` loop, you can just use a single declared function as the handler. I was looking at how the OP appeared to be trying to fix the problem and explaining why his approach was not working.